# How to store one-time data in a MongoDB database?

Tags: mongodb, mern

I am building a personal work/career portfolio web app project, and plan on using MongoDB for my database. (I plan to build the project using MERN stack.) Most of my data is not one-time data (such as education, and work experiences), however I have a few pieces of data (such as my personal summary (the content for my "About Me" section), and skills summary) that are one-time only data (I think "single instance" might be a better fitting term). I would like to store all of the data in a database, and set up an admin-end to manage and edit the data. However, I am not sure how to go about storing the one-time data in my MongoDB database.

One idea I had was to create a collection solely for the one-time data, and only allow the user (me) to update and read the documents in the collection. Another idea I had was placing all of my portfolio data into a single collection called "entries", and giving each "entry" a type (such as "Education", or "Personal Summary"). Then when I retrieve the data from the collection I would gather all the documents with the same value in their type field together. I was thinking of storing each of the types as a constant on my server. However, my biggest concern with both ideas is if they would be considered bad practice of not.

I would be very appreciative if anyone has any advice on how to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had implemented this a while back on one of my small projects, and again after discussing it over with some professionals I'm in contact with, they said that the best approach would be to create a collection with a single document that contains all the information, like the links, about, etc...

One more thing I, was suggested is that we could use Redis solely for the purpose of storing this type of information as well.

Something that I implemented a long time back similar to the one collection, single doc approach: https://github.com/codelancedevs/Sundar-Clinic/tree/local-backend/src/api/app

Working on a similar approach here: https://github.com/kunalkeshan/Cam-O-Genics-Backend

Hope this is of some help, I'm still learning as to what might be the best approach. Open to any suggestions out there!